# Passing arg 2 of `memset' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

I am following a tutorial on http://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/07/19/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-1-stack-based-overflows/ to learn more about exploits. The scripts shown are in perl and I wanted to write it in C I'm having trouble finding a function similar to "\x41" * 10000 in C. I looked around and found memset to be an option but when I use it I keep getting this error whether I was "A" or "\x41" as the 2nd argument. Here is my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *crash;
    crash = fopen("crash.m3u", "w+");
    char junk[10001];
    memset(junk, "A", sizeof(junk));
    fputs(junk, crash);
    fclose(crash);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"A"` is a string, but `memset` takes a character (typed `int`) as its second argument, which would be `'A'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
memset(junk, 'A', sizeof(junk));
```

In C, there is a huge difference between single quotes `'` and double quotes `"`. Single quotes are used for `char` values, and double quotes are used for string (multiple character, or `const char *`) values.

Answer (score 1):

`"A"` resolves to a string, or `char*`, but the second parameter of `memset` is an `int`. Using

```
memset(junk, 'A', sizeof(junk));
```

will work since `'A'` is of type `char`, which can be implicitly cast into an `int`.

Comment: I don't believe so. `gcc` returns 1 for `sizeof('A')` and 4 for `sizeof(int)`

Comment: it's because you are using a C++ compiler. In C `sizeof 'A'` and `sizeof (int)` are the same.

Comment: No, C has disparate `char` and `int` types.

Comment: But character literals have type `int` in C. They're of type `char` in C++, though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a string, you need a character.

Try `\x41' instead of "A" - as given in the web page